# Choose to redirect to 2 loginUrl with Yii?

Tags: php, authentication, yii

I've read an article, [which shows how to redirect to a specified login page](http://www.tipstank.com/2010/05/23/make-yii-redirect-to-the-login-page-i-want/). However, what I want is if user comes to frontend, they should be redirected to frontend-login-page and the similar is applied to backend. Is it possible?

Comment: when user goes to frontend and backend, what do the urls look like? and are frontend and backend separate controllers or modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way should be to determine in a user value as needed

```
Yii::app()->getUser()->setState('LoginReturnUrl', 'frontend/login');
```

or

```
Yii::app()->getUser()->setState('LoginReturnUrl', 'backend/login');
```

and redirect inside your controller:

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl(Yii::app()->getUser()->getState('LoginReturnUrl')));
```

Answer (score 3):

On your configuration file(`main.php`) please set the Login URL.

```
// user
    'user'=>array(
    // enable cookie-based authentication
    'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    // set the url where user must be redirected if authentication needed
    // use null to force 403 HTTP error 
    'loginUrl'=>'/site/login',
    // set here the name of a class
    // that extends CWebUser and it is stored in
    // protected/components/<classname>
    // see: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/cookbook/60/
    'class' => 'WebUser',
    ),
```

Please see this URL: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/59/

And then on your Home Controller(`SiteController.php`) please add this code to make your Index Home can only access by authenticated user.

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
    );
}

/**
 * Specifies the access control rules.
 * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
 * @return array access control rules
 */
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('index', 'action1', 'action2', 'anotherAction'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

Please see this URL: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth

Answer (score 0):

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'loginUrl' => [ 'YourController\YourLogin' ],
    ],
]
```

in main.php.

loginUrl has to be declared with an array